# Querying for possible output event count in a context for a statement

Tags: complex-event-processing, esper

We are using a context defined like this

```
private static final String context = "create context oneHour start(0,*,*,*,*,0) end(59,*,*,*,*,59)";
```

and we are using `epConfig.getEngineDefaults().getThreading().setInternalTimerEnabled(false);` to set internal clock off

our statement is fully aggregated one

```
 @Hint('enable_outputlimit_opt') context oneHour select sum(pkt), ts, region from com.events group by ts,region output all when terminated
```

We are starting the context with `engine.getEPRuntime().sendEvent(new CurrentTimeSpanEvent(event.getTs()));`
and then sending normal events like

```
engine.getEPRuntime().sendEvent(event);
```

However at some point we want to query how many num of aggregated events we could have as output if we end context now thus to avoid memory overhead.

We tried Iterator in esper

```
SafeIterator<EventBean> iterator = statement.safeIterator();
      int i = 0;
      while(iterator.hasNext()) {
        i++;
        EventBean bean = iterator.next();
        Object underlaying = bean.getUnderlying();
        System.out.println(underlaying);
      }
 System.out.println("Agg events " + i);
```

Although this gives an inside of possible output events count, but it waste cpu cycles of iterating over all events.
Is there any other way for this in esper ? Also above iterator is giving result when we change query to `output snapshot` from `output all`

Comment: Which Esper version are asking about? The code suggests that the version is an old old version.

Comment: esper version is 7.1.0

Comment: I don't think Esper is retaining any events since there is no data window and the iterator doesn't iterate over all events.

Comment: We have `output all when terminated`  http://esper.espertech.com/release-7.1.0/esper-reference/html/context.html#context_outputterminated, also iterator is iterating over aggregated events

Comment: This is a fully-aggregated query so its just aggregation state anyway.

Comment: We have a use case of poor aggregation, do we have an api to get count of aggregated events instead of iterating and getting count

Answer (score 0):

Esper isn't retaining any events since there is no data window that is declared. Therefore the iterator doesn't iterate over all events.